# ffmpeg - automatically chopped?

Tags: ffmpeg, iso, dvd

I have an ISO file that I would like to encode it out to mp4 in parts so it's easier to upload to youtube. I am not sure how it handles with chapters etc in this iso file. I have tried

```
ffmpeg -i file.iso newfile.mp4
```

which works great however it's one large file.

I have google and read some where that says if you put a % within the output file, it should automatically give you parts of the video based on the -t you set, so I went ahead and did this

```
ffmpeg -i file.iso -t 30 newfile%.mp4
```

however, the above does not work as it only give me 30 seconds with the file name: newfile%.mp4

Thanks for your time and hoping I can get some help with this. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use -t and -ss in conjunction to do this with a script.
Here is one: http://grapsus.net/blog/post/A-script-for-splitting-videos-using-ffmpeg